# How to send values to a component from dialog service

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to create a custom dialog service. 
For that, I've created a dialog service:

```
import {DialogService,DialogRef,DialogCloseResult } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dialog';  
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";  
import {CustomComponent} from './custom.component'; 

@Injectable()
 export class DialogoService {
     constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) { }
     public confirm(title: string, content?: string): DialogRef {
      return  this.dialogService.open({
              title: title,
          content: CustomComponent ,//This is my component that holds the template
          actions: [
                    {text: 'Yes', primary: true},
                    {text: 'No'}
                   ]
               });
            } }
```

And this is my CustomComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId : module.id,
    selector: 'customcomponent',
    templateUrl: './custom.component.html'
})

export class CustomComponent {
    content : string ;
}
```

And finally my custom.component.html:

```
<div> Content: {{content}} </div>
```

How should I send content parameter from service to dialogService.open function ?

content parameter of dialogService.open can be string, Component or TemplateRef.
In my case, I send CustomComponent as a parameter but can't set title parameter for this component from my service.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Version 0.16 of the dialog adds a `DialogRef.content` field that can be used to pass information to the child component

```
const dialogRef = dialogService.open({ content: MyComponent });
dialogRef.content.instance.foo = "bar";
```

[See the documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialogs/dialog/service/#toc-using-components) for a runnable example.

---

At the time of writing the only way to pass information to the child component is to use a service that will get injected in the component.

An upcoming version of the dialog will pass a ComponentRef to the child component, which will allow you to pass data after the `DialogService.open` call.

Comment: Great news. Thanks

Comment: @LucasMartinez the new dialog version has been released, I've updated the answer with the relevant code.

Comment: I really apreciate this feature. Grate job @Alex Gyoshev

Comment: @AlexGyoshev Will you please provide the updated link with ComponentRef usage described? I am unable to locate the provided answer in KendoUI Angular Dialog API documentation.

Comment: @Jeet Updated. Happy new year :)